# Does open_basedir works recursive?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, security, open-basedir

Does open_basedir works recursive? 
For example if I write in php.ini something like:
`open_basedir=/client3/web3/web`
Does it include all directories in /client3/web3/web (/client3/web3/web/1, /client3/web3/web/2, )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path supplied to the [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting is the root of a directory tree.

> Limit the files that can be opened by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself.

So yes anything below will be accessible.

Answer (score 4):

From the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir):

> open_basedir string
>
> Limit the files that can be opened by PHP to the specified
> **directory-tree**
>
> ....
>
> When you want to restrict access to only the specified directory, end with a slash.

So, your answer is yes.